# Apache Flink on Yarn - savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, flink-streaming

We are using yarn on emr to submit our flink(flink 1.8.0) job. How do we accomplish graceful shutdown with savepoint. The stop command does not recognize -s or -p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink 1.8 does not support a graceful stop with savepoint. This feature was added in Flink 1.9. With 1.8 you can do

```
./bin/flink cancel -s [targetDirectory] <jobID>
```

See the [CLI documentation for version 1.8](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/cli.html#cancel-with-a-savepoint) for more information.